# Animation add mesh part

Tags: animation, armature

For my project I've make an human animation with a first Mesh and Rigify Addon. THe animation works fine, and now i would like to add to the first Mesh an head to become more realistic. How can i do that without restart my animation ?

Thanks for answers,

Theo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is head-mesh there already, you can subdivide the head-mesh further and start adding in details.  The weights get interpolated into the subdivisions, so you won't have to re-animate, re-weight-paint after sub-dividing.

How to sculpt a realistic head is out of the scope of this question, but suffice to say there are plenty of resources on learning that.